# how to pass variable value in URL via file_get_contents

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I want to integrate SMS to my API and try to pass the variables in URL but it says error, no number found.

Please help

```
$sender = "9999708993";
$reply_message = "This is an auto generated message";

echo $sender;
echo $reply_message;

$lines = file_get_contents('http://sms2.oxyzen.in/httpapi/sendsms.php?loginid=myid&password=mypassword&senderid=mysenderid&message=$reply_message&number=$sender');

echo "<pre>$lines</pre>";
```

Answer (score 4):

use double quotes rather than single quotes if you want to put variables in:

```
$lines = file_get_contents("http://sms2.oxyzen.in/httpapi/sendsms.php?loginid=myid&password=mypassword&senderid=mysenderid&message=$reply_message&number=$sender");
```

---

Please try this:

```
$sender = "9999708993";
$reply_message = urlencode("This is an auto generated message");


//I think you need to change these
$loginid='myid';
$mypassword='mypassword';
$mysenderid='mysenderid'; 

$uri = "http://sms2.oxyzen.in/httpapi/sendsms.php?loginid=$myid&password=$mypassword&senderid=$mysenderid&message=$reply_message&number=$sender";
var_dump($uri);
$lines=file_get_contents($uri);
var_dump($lines);
```

Comment: i have tried that as well. and i have got the same message, ERROR | No Number Found

Comment: see addition to the question, please try that

Comment: i have tried addition code as well and i have got this .... string(277) "http://sms2.oxyzen.in/httpapi/sendsms.php?loginid=NOXXA&password=china@123&senderid=MMXCX&message=Welcome to x becho x jeeto contest. &number=9999708993" string(23) "ERROR | No Number Found"

ERROR | No Number Found

Comment: np, please accept the answer if you are happy with it

Answer (score 0):

try cleaning the URL, it might have a new line at the end
trim("$URL");